# ValueError: With n_samples=1, test_size=0.5 and train_size=None

Tags: python

I have this code for Support Vector Machine

```
pick_in = open('data.pickle','rb')
data = pickle.load(pick_in)
pick_in.close()      

print(len(data))

features = []
labels = []

for feature, label in data:
    features.append(feature)
    labels.append(label)
    
xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size= 0.50)

model = SVC(C=1, kernel='poly', gamma='auto')
model.fit(xtrain, ytrain)

prediction = model.predict(xtest)
accuracy = model.score(xtest,ytest)

categories = ['C','NC']

print('Accuracy:', accuracy)
print('Prediction is:',categories[prediction[0]])

myphoto=xtest[0].reshape(224,224)
plt.imshow(myphoto,cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

I am working with 20 images of each category to start. However, I am getting this error:

ValueError: With n_samples=1, test_size=0.5 and train_size=None, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters.

Answer (score 0):

`train_test_split` takes matrices/arrays as input. In other words, the input list has to be 2D matrices. Since your input is a 1D list, `train_test_split` will consider the whole list as just one element, hence the error.

I have not tested this yet, but try the following instead:

```py
 for feature, label in data:
    features.append(list(feature))
    labels.append(list(label))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried that but it says it is not iterable that way

Comment: It was -- ValueError: With n_samples=1, test_size=0.5 and train_size=None, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters. -- But I ncreased the dataset and the same code seems to be working now. Thank you